# How do i change date format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am new to python. I am trying to change the date format. I have date format like this "YYYY/mm/dd", I want to change this format to "mm/dd/YYYY" this format. How to do this.

views.py

```
database = Person.objects.all().filter(name= name).values()
for data in database:
    name = data['name']
    age = data['age']
    dob = data['date_of_birth']
    print(name)
    print(age)
    print(dob)
```

Comment: `datetime` seems overqualified for this job. just do `t = "YYYY/mm/dd".split('/')` and then `'/'.join([t[1], t[2], t[0]])` (gives e.g. 'mm/dd/YYYY').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` methods.

```
from datetime import datetime
a = '2016/02/28'
date = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```